# there is a error detected at the time of inserting to a table

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?PHP
    include("db.php");
    $sql="INSERT INTO registration (`user_name`,'user_email','user_contact_no','user_address','user_dateofbirth','user_gender','user_photo')
    VALUES ('"$_POST['fullname']."','"$_POST['userid']"','"$_POST['cno']"','"$_POST['add']"','"$_POST['dateofbirth']"','"$_POST['gender']"','"echo'<img src= "upload/".$img>'"')";
```

?>

how to fix this

Comment: Hi there, you apparently are a first time asker. please consult https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as a hint: provide error output, error messages can be retrieved from all database wrappers/drivers. you might want to search the web for that error message first, too ;o)

Comment: Maybe coz there is an `echo` on your string? And you concatenate strings with `.` in php

Comment: do not continue with this sql - it is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should learn how to use `prepared statements` in either `mySQLi` or `PDO` - by doing so you would not have encountered this error initially

Answer (score 1):

Check this --

```
<?PHP
    include("db.php");
    $sql="INSERT INTO registration (`user_name`,'user_email','user_contact_no','user_address','user_dateofbirth','user_gender','user_photo')
    VALUES ('".$_POST['fullname']."','".$_POST['userid']."','".$_POST['cno']."','".$_POST['add']."','".$_POST['dateofbirth']."','".$_POST['gender']."','<img src= /upload/'".$img.">')";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

join variables with periods.
escape double quotes used when inserting the img tag.

although you might just want to save the path to the photo instead.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO registration (`user_name`,'user_email','user_contact_no','user_address','user_dateofbirth','user_gender','user_photo')
    VALUES ('".$_POST['fullname']."','".$_POST['userid']."','".$_POST['cno']."','".$_POST['add']."','".$_POST['dateofbirth']."','".$_POST['gender']."','<img src=\"upload/".$img."\"')";
```

without using image tag

```
$sql="INSERT INTO registration (`user_name`,'user_email','user_contact_no','user_address','user_dateofbirth','user_gender','user_photo')
    VALUES ('".$_POST['fullname']."','".$_POST['userid']."','".$_POST['cno']."','".$_POST['add']."','".$_POST['dateofbirth']."','".$_POST['gender']."','upload/".$img."')";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This --

```
<?PHP
    include("db.php");

    $fullname = $_POST['fullname'];
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $cno = $_POST['cno'];
    $add = $_POST['add'];
    $dateofbirth = $_POST['dateofbirth'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];

    $sql="INSERT INTO registration (`user_name`,'user_email','user_contact_no','user_address','user_dateofbirth','user_gender','user_photo')
    VALUES ('".$fullname"','".$userid."','".$cno."','".$add."','".$dateofbirth."','".$gender."','<img src= /upload/'".$img.">')";
?>
```